# Does the Lorem or Rand functions exist at all?

Tags: excel, ms-office

So I saw on numerous websites there was such a command as LOREM() to generate Lorem Ipsum text, and RAND() to generate example text in your system language. Some mention only Excel, some mention Word, Excel, and PowerPoint (are there functions on these?) and some only Word and PowerPoint.

I tried inputting those in my Excel Sheet to no avail. My Excel is in French, so maybe the translation is wrong, but there doesn't seem to be any page on those two functions in support.microsoft.com… LOREM() shouldn't be translated in anything else than LOREM() anyway, so I'm puzzled.

Are those two real, or is that an office urban legend ?

Comment: RAND() exists in Excel but it generates random numbers. You can use RAND in Word to generate the Lorem text, but I've never heard of an equivalent in Excel.

Comment: `=LOREM()`, while it looks like an Excel formula, is actually a hidden feature of Word. It's of limited value since it outputs the same 5 sentences every time. `=RAND()` also produces text in Word, though despite the name this too appears to be the same 5 sentences every time (but this time sentences from the Word documentation itself). PowerPoint also suports `=LOREM()` and `=RAND()`, though its output is different from Word's. Excel supports `RAND()` as a proper function and `LOREM()` not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems to not exist in Excel, the solution I have found is to use =lorem() in Word, and copy/paste into Excel. I doubt anybody in this forum requires that answer to be stated, but hey, maybe they are lacking coffee and need a jolt of the obvious.

Answer (score -1):

As Excel is mostly about numbers, there is a function called **RANDARRAY** that will generate a set of random numbers across a range that you set.  It can also be used to select random words.

### Numbers

The function parameters are:

```
=RANDARRAY([rows],[columns],[min],[max],[whole_number])
```

**Example:**

```
=RANDARRAY(5,5,1,10,TRUE)
```

This formula is entered into a single cell and the results will spill across other rows and columns.

[image]

### Words

The same function can be used with the **INDEX** function to populate random words from a list into a grid.

The **RANDARRAY** function generates a five by five grid of numbers between one and 26.
The **INDEX** function matches each number to a word in a range.

```
=INDEX(A2:A27,RANDARRAY(5,5,1,26,TRUE))
```

[image]

A slightly different way, uses the same formula but embeds an array of words in the formula rather than referencing a range.

```
=INDEX(
{"Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet",",","consectetur","adipiscing","elit","sed","do",
"eiusmod","tempor","incididunt","ut","labore","et","dolore","magna","aliqua",".","Ut",
"enim","ad","minim","veniam"},RANDARRAY(5,5,1,26,TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't at all relevant to the OP's question...